# Getting error on an SQL query, but the database is being updated with the the correct info

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file-upload

I'm getting the error: **mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/content/57/8912457/html/brick-academy/add_file.php on line 34.**

I can't figure out why it's giving that error, considering the code looks fine and it is inputing the correct data into the correct fields in the database.

The error is stopping the rest of my script from running.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Code:

```
include_once('resources/init.php');
include_once('user_check.php');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$teacher = $_POST['teacher'];

$query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT name_first, name_last FROM teachers WHERE teacher_id='$teacher'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$name_first = $row['name_first'];
$name_last = $row['name_last'];
$folder_name = $name_last . "-" . $name_first . "-ID-" . $teacher . "/";


$dirname = "files/" . $folder_name;
if(!is_dir($dirname)){
    mkdir($dirname);
}

$dirname = $dirname .  $_FILES['file']['name'];


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $dirname)){

    $query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "INSERT INTO documents SET id_teacher = '$teacher', name = '$name', document =  '$dirname'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    header("location:file_manager.php");
}
```

Comment: $GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"] doesn't appear to be an initialized mysqli link

Comment: Added the rest of the code for your benefit. It's in one of the includes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);`

If you look at the documentation for [mysqli_query](http://php.net/mysqli_query),  it shows that it will return a boolean value for any insert queries instead of a mysql resource.
Since you're not even attempting to use $row in any place,  you can get rid of the line.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that. I have no need for the $row variable at all. I appreciate the help. I'll mark your answer correct as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

to this:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
```